# EF Core 5 - Globally set the default DeleteBehavior

Tags: entity-framework-core

For required foreign keys, the default DeleteBehavior is Cascade in EF Core 5. But I don't want a developer accidentally deleting a bunch of primary records along with the children records. So I want to set ClientSetNull as the default even for required foreign key relationships. The only way I found so far is to configure this in the FluentAPI. But I want to avoid fluent api as much as possible by following the conventions. Is there any way to globally set the DeleteBehavior in EF Core 5?

Comment: Currently EF Core does not provide a public way of customizing conventions, and as you know, the convention for required relationships is cascade.  Hence the answer is no, you have to use fluent configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately no, here is the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Metadata/Conventions/CascadeDeleteConvention.cs#L66) for the convention in question, as we can see, there are no options, it's purely based on `foreignKey.IsRequired`.

Comment: Yeah I see that in the code. Thanks.